# 404 error for subdirectory pages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I deployed my website on google app engine, which is working fine unless I try to open a subdirectory of the website. E.g opening example.com/dir will give a 404 error even if i have the directory uploaded/deployed. My app.yaml is as follows:

```
runtime: php72


handlers:
- url: /
static_files: public/index.html
upload: public/index.html

- url: /
static_dir: public


# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
static_files: \1
upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
application_readable: true

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
script: \1
```

Let me know if you need any other detail about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was a copy-paste error adding code to serverfault, but the indentation on your YAML is not correct, which might cause this error. It should be:

```
runtime: php72


handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: public


# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  application_readable: true

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

Answer (score 0):

The only accepted value for the "script" parameter in the PHPv7.2 runtime for App Engine standard environemnt is "auto", as described here [1]. It is suggested using a web framework (such as Laravel, Symfony, or similar) with in-app routing to execute a script when a request hits a specific route.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences#migrating_your_appyaml_file

Remember that if you are using PHP 7.2 and App Engine standard environment, this runtime is in Beta, and this feature might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy.

Please, try this and let me know the results.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref